# Syntax error on Scheme tail-recursive function

Tags: recursion, scheme, syntax-error

I'm creating a tail recursive function that evaluates a polynomial by passing a list of coefficients and an x value.

example: evaluate x^3 + 2x^2 + 5, so the user would pass the list '(5 0 2 1) and an x like 1 in a functional call (poly '(5 0 2 1) 1).

I can't figure out why i'm getting the following error:

> if: bad syntax in: (if (null? (cdr lst)) (+ total (car lst))
>   eval-poly-tail-helper ((cdr lst) x (+ (* (expt x n) (car lst)) total)
>   (+ 1 n)))

```
(define (poly lst x)
  (poly-assistant lst x 0 0))


(define (poly-assistant lst x total n)
   (if (null? (cdr lst))
      (+ total (car lst))
      poly-assistant((cdr lst) x (+ (* (expt x n) (car lst)) total) (+ 1 n))))
```

Comment: Please try to do your homework by yourself! Your fix-my-code question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You need a left paren before  `poly-assistant` in the last line.

In Scheme, function applications start with a left paren. And `if` takes 2 or 3  operands.

Use a better editor (e.g. `emacs`) able to match parenthesis.

The two left parenthesis before `cdr` looks suspicious. You might need only one.

Learn to use your Scheme debugger, or at least add debugging prints.

Comment: Thanks but i'm receiving the following error after running it.

application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: (0 4 1)
  arguments...:

Comment: Disregard. I actually found the error and you're right about using a better editor.